# Convert JSON to formGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

I have following JSON data,

```
{
  "page": 2,
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Till now, I have manually created formGroup and assign data in it by using for loop.

```
  result1 = new FormGroup({
    page: this.fb.control(''),
    total: this.fb.control(''),
    data: this.fb.array([])
  });

  this.getUsersWithoutFormGroup().subscribe((data: pageData) =>{
    let users = this.result1.get('data') as FormArray
    data.data.forEach(element => {
      users.push(this.fb.group({
          id: [element.id],
          email: [element.email]
        })
      ) 
    });
  })
```

I am not sure, if I need to create formGroup and formArray manually, if I have long json data, or we have any inbuilt method which I can use?

I tried below, but it gives all controls as formControls, even array is also coming as controls.

```
this.fb.group(data)
```

Do we have any existing method which can provide correct formGroup by just passing JSON object?

Comment: Personally creating long-form manually is better if you have need to put validation etc on them, you are already using a for-loop for array and from group only needs to be made once.

Comment: True, but I have no validations, just need to display data in table and few in textboxes.

Comment: You need to do as you are currently doing as you have a formarray that needs formgroups inside. So doing a loop and adding like you are doing is correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.result1.value = [...data];
```

Know I'm not sure if we can change a form directly assigning its *value*, so if the above did'nt work, try this in this way:

```
if (data != null) {
   this.result1.patchValue(data);
}
```

EDIT:

```
if (data != null) {
   this.result1.patchValue(data);
   this.result1.patchValue(
      { data: data.data }
   );
}
```

Comment: No, we cannot assign value directly to formgroup, and patchValue is creating formArray for array data, but it don't add inner items in formArray, so formArray is empty, 0 length.

Comment: And, could you please test if the new edit I added to my answer right now does work? Thxs! If it doesn't work either, I will delete my wrong answer.